# How do i server static html file with ring handler in clojure?

Tags: clojure, ring

I am trying to server html over a ring based api server path . however everytime i hit the endpoint , i am getting this wierd error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No implementation of method: :write-body-to-stream of protocol: #'ring.core.protocols/StreamableResponseBody found for class: clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap
    at clojure.core$_cache_protocol_fn.invokeStatic(core_deftype.clj:583) ~[clojure-1.10.1.jar:?]
    at clojure.core$_cache_protocol_fn.invoke(core_deftype.clj:575) ~[clojure-1.10.1.jar:?]
    at ring.core.protocols$eval18503$fn__18504$G__18494__18513.invoke(protocols.clj:8) ~[?:?]
    at ring.util.servlet$update_servlet_response.invokeStatic(servlet.clj:106) ~[?:?]
    at ring.util.servlet$update_servlet_response.invoke(servlet.clj:91) ~[?:?]
    at ring.util.servlet$update_servlet_response.invokeStatic(servlet.clj:95) ~[?:?]
    at ring.util.servlet$update_servlet_response.invoke(servlet.clj:91) ~[?:?]
    at ring.adapter.jetty$proxy_handler$fn__18623.invoke(jetty.clj:27) ~[?:?]
```

Here is what my api is returning.

```
{:status 200
:body   (resource-response "index.html" {:root "public"})}
```

Whereas if i hit the index.html path directly it is accessible at this route

```
http://localhost:8080/index.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error `No implementation of method: :write-body-to-stream of protocol: #'ring.core.protocols/StreamableResponseBody found for class: clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap` because as a body you return a PersistentArrayMap instead of something that can be encoded as the body of a Ring HTTP response.

`resource-response` already returns a full response map (a PersistentArrayMap):

```clj
(resource-response "index.html")
;; => {:status 200,
;;     :headers
;;     {"Content-Length" "0", "Last-Modified" "Mon, 16 Nov 2020 14:22:48 GMT"},
;;     :body
;;     #object[java.io.File 0x239d3777 "/index.html"]}
```

so no need to wrap it in `{:status 200, :body ...}` since it becomes `{:status 200 :body {:status 200, ...}}` which lead to that error. To fix it your API can directly return:

```clj
(resource-response "index.html" {:root "public"})
```

Comment: Thanks for elaborating on the problem. This really helped.